# TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterator, typeerror

I am trying to write a very basic nearest neighbor calculation. I basically want to see what t looks like but I got this type error. When I asked the funciton to return just t it said "". When I asked it to turn to list it threw "TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array Python "

How do I fix this please?

```
...

t = np.array(map(lambda v:
             map(lambda w: distance(v, w, L), x_train.values),
             x_test.values)) 

...
```

Full trace:
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is `np.array` does not take an iterator, you need convert to `list` first, as below:

```
t = np.array(list(map(lambda v: map(lambda w: distance(v, w, L),
                      x_train.values), x_test.values)))
```

As per `numpy.array` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), the required parameter must be:

> An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose
>   array method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence.

Alternatively, use [`numpy.fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) and remember to supply `dtype`, e.g. `dtype=float`.

Comment: When I printed t, it gave me a list of items similar to "<map object at 0x000001DB71AFB2B0>". How do I actually see the result of t?

Comment: you need to input a `list` into `np.array`, as per my example code, or use `np.fromiter` instead of `np.array` and supply a `dtype` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to load a 0-d numpy array with `arr1 = np.load(..., allow_pickle=True)`. To access the item stored as being a np.array, use:

```
arr1.item()
```

For instance, if the type stored is a `dict d1 = {'item1':42, 'item2':np.array(1,3)}` we can get the value as such: `v1 = arr1.item()['item2']`.

**Important:** Loading with `allow_pickle=True` is brings security risks and is not recommended.