# TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array Python (Image Detection)

Tags: python

I am trying to make an object detector that will take input from the `def(x1,y1,x2,y2)`

but the error I get when I run the code is TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

Error Line, it shows line 28 so the `for (x,y,w,h) in inp`

is this code even going to **work?**

Code I made:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui

def object_detection(File_Name, x1 ,y1 ,x2 ,y2):
    F1 = File_Name
    while (True):
        screen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1,y1,x2,y2)))
        last_time = time.time()
        cv2.imshow('window',cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            
        inp = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(File_Name)
        inp = np.array(inp)
            
            
        if inp is None:
            print("No " + F1 + ' Found On Screen')
            
            
        if inp is not None:
            print(F1 + 'Found On' + File_Name)
            
            
        for (x,y,w,h) in inp:
            rect = cv2.rectangle(screen,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

object_detection('Capture.PNG', 6, 138,767, 827)
```

Comment: [When the error occurs what is `inp`?](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) Is there a boolean test for a zero-dimension array?

Comment: Searching with the error message is often productive. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48643256/2823755 - There are others.

Comment: inp is an input source from ```File_Name``` for cv2 show an outpiut

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Please read [mre]. Searching with the error message, it sounds like ``pyautogui.locateOnScreen(...`  might be returning an iterator. You can verify that by [Catching the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print `inp` and its datatype. To accommodate you should change `inp = np.array(inp)` to `inp1 = np.array(inp)` and use `inp1` in subsequent statements - that will preserve the original for your troubleshooting.

Comment: the data type of inp is a string not an int

Comment: `for thing in np.array('abcdefg'): print(thing)` --> `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array`. If `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` is returning a string then that is the problem. You need to figure out why it is returning a string - it is supposed to return `a 4-integer tuple: (left, top, width, height)` or `None`.  Again, without a [mre] it will be hard for *us* to diagnose.

Comment: so how would i make a object detector with out tensorflow?