# TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array with scraper?

Tags: python, api

I am running the below code in order to scrape from Google, but I get this error code when I try to run from terminal

```
 File "Coordinate-Scraper.py", line 33, in <module>
    for loc in locations_array:
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

I keep trying to figure out what may be causing it. Any ideas? I have added in a part of the code to account for Google breaking after several hundred observations, but it still refuses to run.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import csv
import sys
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Locations_file1 = 'Locations_file1.csv'
Locations_Sheet = 'Sheet1'
Col_name = 'Locations'

try:
    if Locations_file1.split(".")[1] == 'csv':
        locations_df = pd.read_excel(Locations_file1, sheetname=Locations_Sheet)
        locations_array = np.asarray(locations_df[Col_name])
    elif Locations_file1.split(".")[1] == 'csv':
        locations_df = pd.read_csv(Locations_file1)
        locations_array = locations_df[Col_name]
except:
    locations_array = np.asarray(Locations_file1)
    
features = ['Location', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']
Complete_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=features)
c = 0
for loc in locations_array:

    if c < 223:
        c+=1
        continue
    desired_location = loc
    search_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='
    url = search_url + str(desired_location.replace(' ','+'))
    r = requests.get(url)

    # print(json.dumps(r.text))
    content = r.text
    # content = r.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
    body = soup.find('body')
    # print(body)
    # break
    map_class = body.find('a',href=lambda href: href and "maps" in href)
    # map_class = body.find('a',,{'class' :'VGHMXd'})
    # print(map_class)
    map_url = map_class.get('href')
    r_map = requests.get(map_url)
    content_map = r_map.text

    soup_map = BeautifulSoup(content_map, features="html.parser")
    head = soup_map.find('head')
    url_long_lat = head.find_all('meta')[8].get('content')
    Lat, Long = url_long_lat[url_long_lat.find('center=')+len('center='):url_long_lat.rfind('&zoom')].split('%2C')
    location_info = pd.DataFrame([[desired_location,Lat,Long]])
    location_info.columns = features
    Complete_df = Complete_df.append(location_info, ignore_index = True)
    print(Complete_df)
    Complete_df.to_csv('Locations_Latitude_Longitude.csv')
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643256/typeerror-iteration-over-a-0-d-array-python

Comment: I did, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Apparently `locations_array` is not what you expect. To debug this, we'd have to have that file. Or you can just go step by step yourself with a debugger of your choice.

Comment: So you would need an actual copy of the csv file?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I should note: I have tried this code on two of my friends' computers. It actually works on one computer but not on the other other (or of course on my own). Any idea why that might be? I have to get it to work on mine.

Comment: It could be then version of the libraries or even Python itself. We have no way of knowing. In order to answer this one would need to reproduce the problem, so yeah, CSV that demonstrates the issue would be helpful. Otherwise there's little to work on.

Comment: I explained why that erraor is occuring in my answer. An exception is being thrown in the try block. Also, I would suggest to check for file formats with `str.endswith()`. This will protect from bad file names like `my_data.vcs.xls` and it is better performance by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues there.

1. I believe your if statement: `if Locations_file1.split(".")[1] == 'csv':` should be checking for `'xlsx'` or other spreadshit format.
2. You have that error because you are getting an exception in your `try` block.
   In `except` block, you are trying to convert the file name `Locations_file1` into np array, which is resulting in `locations_array` having only the value of `Locations_file1` string. So if you print `locations_array` you will get Locations_file1.csv on your console.

Interestingly, `locations_array` is an object wich has __str__() function returning the value of the string, but the verabile is 0 dimensional array. So the datafeild of the np.array object is empty.

In simple terms

```
strs = "Hello world"

arr = np.asarray(strs)
print(arr.__str__())
print(arr)
print(arr.__repr__())
for i in arr:
    print(i)
```

gives following output:

```
Hello world
Hello world
array('Hello wolrd', dtype='<U11')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/tests.py", line 73, in <module>
    for i in arr:
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

**Update:**

Now if to address the issue in your `try:...except:` block, first of all, you are catching all possible exceptions there and ignoring them assuming that if reading the file didn't work, then it must be already read. But your code does not indicate that it's read in case of failure. I would suggest changing your `except` block:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This would give you an idea of what went wrong. I dare to assume two possible cases:

1. Your file is bad and you fail to read it to `pandas.DataFrame`
2. Your file and eventually your DataFrame does not contain `Col_name` which caries value `"Locations"` in your code.

Comment: I tried changing the 'csv' to 'xlsx', now all I see is "== RESTART: my computer etc.". How can I change the code within the ```try``` block to make this work?

Comment: I have updated my answer with suggestions to identify the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in this part of the code:

```
try:
    if Locations_file1.split(".")[1] == 'csv':
        locations_df = pd.read_excel(Locations_file1, sheetname=Locations_Sheet)
        locations_array = np.asarray(locations_df[Col_name])
    elif Locations_file1.split(".")[1] == 'csv':
        locations_df = pd.read_csv(Locations_file1)
        locations_array = locations_df[Col_name]
except:
    locations_array = np.asarray(Locations_file1)
```

Your `if` and `elif` statements are both triggered on the condition `Locations_file1.split(".")[1] == 'csv'`. There is no `else` statement so, if `Locations_file1.split(".")[1]` does not equal `'csv'`, `locations_array` is not getting populated. You make be expecting the except part of the code to catch all other cases, but that may not be triggering, because it's theoretically possible to have a case where your conditions are not true but no exception was thrown. Another error may be hiding behind this one, but I think that's the source here.